# UseEffect does not load at the right time Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Hello I have created a modal component, in order to display the details of one of my products from a list in my database. So I get the id that I send back to firebase.

My concern is that since it's a modal, it makes useEffect to the loading of my main component and not the opening of the modal, so the id is asked before the opening of the modal and so it doesn't know it.

I would like to do useEffect only when I open my modal.

Do you have an idea? Thank you very much.

```
export function ProjetDetails({showModalPD, setshowModalPD, id, setid}) { 



const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);
const [type, setType] = useState('');

var IdProjet = id;

console.log(IdProjet);



useEffect( () => {
              fire
              .firestore()
              .collection("orders")
              .doc(id)
              .get()
              .then((doc) => {
                setType(doc.get("type"));
                
              });

              console.log(IdProjet);
}, []);
```

Comment: Your code seems correct but i think your business Logic is wrong useEffect with [] works like componentDidMount so your Component using useEffect [] right after render if your id comes late you can use useEffect [props.id]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call useEffect, you can specify what changes in dependencies trigger it (second argument).

You are currently using `[]` meaning it would only be triggered once.

If you had a properly configured linter (with [exhaustive-deps](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920)), it would have complained that a dependency `id` isn't passed in as the second argument to `useEfect` even though it is used in the hook `.doc(id)`

try changing to

```js
useEffect( () => {
  if (!id) return;

  fire
    .firestore()
    .collection("orders")
    .doc(id)
    .get()
    .then((doc) => {
       setType(doc.get("type"));
    });

  console.log(IdProjet);
}, [id]);
```

If you also want firebase to be called whenever you open the modal, you can add that as a dependency (`}, [id, showModalPD]);`) to firebase. You wouldn't want to call firebase when it changes to false so can add a check for that too.

When anything in your dependency for useEffect changes, it would be called again.

Comment: Just added it, but i have this error FirebaseError: Function CollectionReference.doc() cannot be called with an empty path. because when I reload my app, doc id is not defined since I have to click on open modal to define it

Comment: you could have a check in useEffect that only calls firebase when `id` exists....I'd update the answer to reflect this

Comment: It does not take into account real-time changes as well. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `real-time changes`

Comment: When I edit my value of "type" i have to close and reopen the modal to see change.

Comment: I need to call my database with another function to update the display?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229466/discussion-between-delis-and-pierre-torres).